# Deserializing JSON strings using GSON in Android

Tags: java, android, json, gson

This might be a bit long so please bear with me..

I'm working on a project in Android. I have a JSON string that i need to deserialize into objects representing the JSON structure,  the JSON string is something like below:

```
{"parents":[
    {"parent":{
            "id":1,
            "name":"Sam",
            "childs":[
                {
                    "child":{
                        "id":1,
                        "name":"Alice",
                        "books":[
                            {
                                "book":{
                                    "id":1,
                                    "name":"Alice in Wonderland"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        } 

    }    
]}
```

Note that for arrays there are repeating values (i.e. many parent and many child) i just put one line here to make it short.

With this i created classes to accomodate the structure:

```
public class Containers{
    private List<Parent> parents;
    //setter and getter..
}

public static class Parent extends CommonItem {
    private List<Child> childs;
    //setter and getter..
}

public static class Child extends CommonItem {
    private List<Book> books;
    //setter and getter..
}

public class CommonItem{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    //setter and getter
}
```

Note that i'd created a common class to accommodate the repeating attributes.
Below is how i parse them using GSON:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Containers parents = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Containers.class);
```

After parsing (there're no error) i try to retrieve the objects. The number of object count in the parents list is correct (i.e. there are 5 parents in the JSON string, and there are 5 Parent objects in the parents List). However, all their attributes are not there, and the child tree are missing as well.

I'd tried numerous configuration, including remove the extended class and put all the id and name in the respective classes but the result is still the same.

Anyone can give me any pointer that where did i go wrong?

Thanx a bunch!

Comment: ops... there's another class for Book i didn't put in but it follows the pattern as how Child is. Plus all three classes of Parent, Child and Book are inner class of Containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON and Java class mismatch.

Lets read

```
{"parents":[
    {"parent":{
            "id":1,
            "name":"Sam",
            "childs":[
                {
                    "child":{
                        "id":1,
                        "name":"Alice",
                        "books":[
                            {
                                "book":{
                                    "id":1,
                                    "name":"Alice in Wonderland"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        } 

    }    
]}
```

Your top object has a `List` of class that has `parents` as it's attribute. Your Java class `Container` has `parents` attribute. Good.

Now this list `parents` is a `List` of objects that has `parent` attribute. Does your `Parent` object has `parent` attribute? No.

Go further down, each `Parent` has `id`, `name`, and a `List` of objects as `childs` (children, should be) attribute that has `child` attribute, does your `Child` class has it? No.

Similarly, goes for `books`.

Did you try your classes on JSON like

```
{"parents":[
        {
            "id":1,
            "name":"Sam",
            "childs":[
                    {
                        "id":1,
                        "name":"Alice",
                        "books":[
                            {
                                    "id":1,
                                    "name":"Alice in Wonderland"
                            }
                        ]
                    }

            ]
        }  
]}
```

Comment: Thanx. After adding in a middle tier of container class to include the  parent, child and book attribute respectively, I finally got it working.